# Unbound module Graphics Ocaml on Linux mint

Tags: graphics, compilation, ocaml, libraries, unbound

i have read multiple identical problem but answers dont fix it.
*The OCaml toplevel, version 4.11.0+dev0-2019-10-18*
**opam list**

```
# Packages matching: installed
# Name              # Installed # Synopsis
base-bigarray       base
base-threads        base
base-unix           base
conf-libX11         1           Virtual package relying on an Xlib system instal
conf-pkg-config     1.1         Virtual package relying on pkg-config installati
dune                2.4.0       Fast, portable, and opinionated build system
dune-configurator   2.4.0       Helper library for gathering system configuratio
dune-private-libs   2.4.0       Private libraries of Dune
graphics            5.1.0       The OCaml graphics library
ocaml               4.10.0      The OCaml compiler (virtual package)
ocaml-base-compiler 4.10.0      Official release 4.10.0
ocaml-config        1           OCaml Switch Configuration
```

**opam install graphics
[NOTE] Package graphics is already installed (current version is 5.1.0).**

**ocamlfind query -predicates native -a-format graphics**

```
ocamlfind: Package `graphics' not found
me@2020:~$   /home/ivg/.opam/fresh/lib/ocaml/graphics.cmxa
bash: /home/ivg/.opam/fresh/lib/ocaml/graphics.cmxa: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

**ocamlfind ocamlopt -package graphics**

```
ocamlfind: Package `graphics' not found
```

**ls `ocamlc -where`/graphics***

```
ls: impossible d'accéder à '/usr/local/lib/ocaml/graphics*': Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

**sudo apt install libx11-dev**

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
libx11-dev est déjà la version la plus récente (2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.2).
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 8 non mis à jour.
```

I dont understand what is wrong, it seems to be installed but it cant use it properly ?

**ocamlc graphics.cma test1.ml -o test1**

```
File "test1.ml", line 3, characters 5-13:
3 | open Graphics;;
         ^^^^^^^^
Error: Unbound module Graphics
```

Answer (score 3):

From https://caml.inria.fr/:

> Since OCaml 4.09, the graphics library is distributed as an external
>   package.

Hence you have to specify to **ocamlc** where to find the corresponding **cma** file using the **-I** option and **ocamlfind** :

```
ocamlc -I $(ocamlfind query graphics) graphics.cma test1.ml -o test1
```

Using **utop** you will have to start with the directive `#require "graphics";;` before doing `open Graphics;;`

Comment: opam list
conf-libX11    1            
conf-m4                      
conf-pkg-config        
cppo                  
dune                 
dune-configurator     
dune-private-libs   
graphics            5.1.0   
ocaml               4.10.0      
ocaml-base-compiler 4.10.0      
ocaml-config        1          
ocamlbuild          0.14.0      
ocamlfind           1.8.1       
topkg               1.0.1       
utop                2.4.3       
zed                 2.0.7       
$ utop
La commande « utop » n'a pas été trouvée, mais peut être installée avec :
sudo apt install utop

Comment: yes ; i'd rather reinstall ocaml4.08 to be quiet. but it's hard to uninstall it.                    sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove opam*                                                                        Le paquet « opam » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 8 non mis à jour.                      
opam uninstall ocaml
Your request can't be satisfied:
  - Package ocaml-base-compiler is part of the base for this compiler and can't be changed

No solution found, exiting